# Can you set breakpoints in code under test when using cucumber?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm just learning cucumber for test automation, and would like to know if it's possible to use it to debug the application the automation is for?

So basically I'd like to know if it can be used to debug the application being developed?

Thanks.
Les

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as your running the instance of the application under test in debug mode you can set breakpoints and debug as you normally would when interacting with it manually. Cucumber does nothing that would prevent this.

Comment: But how do you write steps in the scenario and the supporting Java file to interact with the application? So if I'm debugging a REST app, I put code in the Java file to make the REST calls?

Comment: Yes exactly, and if you run the REST app in debug mode it will break on any breakpoint when the API is called from the cucumber step definition in the Java file.

Comment: However if your only goal is to debug the application during development on your local computer i would use tools such as Postman to simulate different calls from a client. Cucumber is a tool you use when you want to run the same test scenario many times, most often on a build server. Most web frameworks such as Spring also have their own libraries to run integration tests with JUnit so that the tests can easily be run as part of the build process of the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can start any java application (say you have prepared build for testing) with remote debugging enabled. So that your steps would be:

1. Start app you would like to test with remote debugging enabled (see docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/introclientissues005.html))
2. In IDE open that app sources and connect to that debugger port you have set up on step 1
3. Put some breakpoints
4. Run your cucumber tests

Since now as soon as your Cucumber tests will make your app hit break-point the service will stop and you will be able to manipulate the state through IDE.

**P.S.** - Since your Cucumber tests will be running separately in regular way, stopping the service at the breakpoint will lead to timeout error on client side after certain time of connection inactivity. Possible solution is to configure your client to accept longer pauses.